# JavaScript: Prevent Array.push()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sealed object with an array member on which I want to prevent direct pushes.

```
var myModule = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var a = (function () {
        var _b = {},
            _c = _c = "",
            _d = [];
        Object.defineProperty(_b, "c", {
            get: function () { return _c; }
        });
        Object.defineProperty(_b, "d", {
            get { return _d; }
        });
        _b.addD = function (newD) {
            _d.push(newD);
        };
        Object.seal(_b);
        return _b;
    }());
    var _something = { B: _b };
    return {
        Something: _something,
        AddD: _b.addD
    };
}());

myModule.Something.c = "blah"; // doesn't update = WIN!!
myModule.AddD({}); // pushed = WIN!
myModule.Something.d.push({}); // pushed = sadness
```

How can I prevent the push?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for all the thoughts.  I eventually need the JSON to send to the server.  It looks like I might need to use an object for the array then figure out a way to generate and return the JSON needed, or change *_something* to use .slice().  Will play and report.

Comment: You could override the `push` prototype, but I wouldn't recommend it. Why not make it private variable?

Comment: It's less efficient, but you could make your getters return a copy of the array, so that pushing onto it won't have any effect on the object.

Comment: What @Barmar said. Or, analyze why you want to even allow access to `d` in the first place. Maybe instead you could provide methods like `forEachD(...)` or something, so people can still do the things that make sense, but not the things that don't.

Comment: for d: `get { return _d.slice(); }` should do what you want safe and cheap

Comment: FYI: push isn't the only way of adding data into the array, you'd need to cater for splice and unshift, if removing is an issue, then you'll also need to look out for shift & pop - basically, there are many ways for someone to alter the array so returning a copy as @Barmar suggested may be best unless you require it be a persistent instance for something like angular.

Comment: I have a pretty useful method I've just written, but it requires a bit of fine tuning to neaten it up and make it more extendable if others take a copy and use it in the future. Need sleep though, will try to post tomorrow after work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, [dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis)!

I used the *slice* method:

```
var myModule = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var a = (function () {
        var _b = {},
            _c = _c = "",
            _d = [];
        Object.defineProperty(_b, "c", {
            get: function () { return _c; }
        });
        Object.defineProperty(_b, "d", {
            get { return _d.slice(); } // UPDATED
        });
        _b.updateC = function (newValue) {
            _c = newValue;
        };
        _b.addD = function (newD) {
            _d.push(newD);
        };
        Object.seal(_b);
        return _b;
    }());
    var _something = { B: _b };
    return {
        Something: _something,
        AddD: _b.addD
    };
}());

myModule.Something.c = "blah"; // doesn't update = WIN!!
myModule.AddD({}); // pushed = WIN!
myModule.Something.d.push({}); // no more update = happiness
```

This allows me to protect from direct *push* calls enforcing some logic.

Answer (score 2):

you could override the push method:

```
var _d = [];
_d.__proto__.push = function() { return this.length; }
```

and when you need to use it in your module, call `Array.prototype.push`:

```
_b.addD = function (newD) {
    Array.prototype.push.call(_d, newD);
};
```

Comment: Just keep in mind if you DO decide to do this, you will be defining the `push` method for **all** arrays... thereby not enabling you to push to **any** arrays. One trick you could do is to add a super class to your particular array and overwrite THAT prototype so that normal arrays still have regular functionality

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to assign to `arr.push()`?

Comment: I think that will happen only if you override Array.prototype.push.

Comment: @molow is correct. I am so used to writing in other languages that refer to arrays as `arr`. I believe this will do what you want it to do. However, the same thing applies in that you will no longer be able to `push` to this array. Essentially you will lock it.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution and `arr.push = function(){}` will both still not stop you using the push function on that array

Comment: My point is exactly that, the code in your `addD` could be run outside his container object as `Array.prototype.push.call(myModule.Something.d, newD)`. I'm not saying any of your code is invalid, it's just worth knowing that it's not waterproof

Comment: Yes, but not directly

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any performance tests on this, but this certainly helps to protect your array.

```
(function(undefined) {
    var protectedArrays = [];
    protectArray = function protectArray(arr) {
        protectedArrays.push(arr);
        return getPrivateUpdater(arr);
    }
    var isProtected = function(arr) {
        return protectedArrays.indexOf(arr)>-1;
    }
    var getPrivateUpdater = function(arr) {
        var ret = {};
        Object.keys(funcBackups).forEach(function(funcName) {
            ret[funcName] = funcBackups[funcName].bind(arr);
        });
        return ret;
    }

    var returnsNewArray = ['Array.prototype.splice'];
    var returnsOriginalArray = ['Array.prototype.fill','Array.prototype.reverse','Array.prototype.copyWithin','Array.prototype.sort'];
    var returnsLength = ['Array.prototype.push','Array.prototype.unshift'];
    var returnsValue = ['Array.prototype.shift','Array.prototype.pop'];

    var funcBackups = {};
    overwriteFuncs(returnsNewArray, function() { return []; });
    overwriteFuncs(returnsOriginalArray, function() { return this; });
    overwriteFuncs(returnsLength, function() { return this.length; });
    overwriteFuncs(returnsValue, function() { return undefined; });

    function overwriteFuncs(funcs, ret) {
        for(var i=0,c=funcs.length;i<c;i++)
        {
            var func = funcs[i];
            var funcParts = func.split('.');
            var obj = window;
            for(var j=0,l=funcParts.length;j<l;j++)
            {
                (function() {
                    var part = funcParts[j];
                    if(j!=l-1) obj = obj[part];
                    else if(typeof obj[part] === "function")
                    {
                        var funcBk = obj[part];
                        funcBackups[funcBk.name] = funcBk;
                        obj[part] = renameFunction(funcBk.name, function() {
                            if(isProtected(this)) return ret.apply(this, arguments);
                            else return funcBk.apply(this,arguments);
                        });
                    }
                })();
            }
        }
    }
    function renameFunction(name, fn) {
        return (new Function("return function (call) { return function " + name +
            " () { return call(this, arguments) }; };")())(Function.apply.bind(fn));
    };
})();
```

You would use it like so:

```
var myArr = [];
var myArrInterface = protectArray(myArr);
myArr.push(5); //Doesn't work, but returns length as expected
myArrInterface.push(5); //Works as normal
```

This way, you can internally keep a copy of the interface that isn't made global to allow your helper funcs to modify the array as normal, but any attempt to use `.push` `.splice` etc will fail, either directly, or using the `.bind(myArr,arg)` method.

It's still not completely watertight, but a pretty good protector. You could potentially use the `Object.defineProperty` method to generate protected properties for the first 900 indexes, but I'm not sure of the implications of this. There is also the method `Object.preventExtensions()` but I'm unaware of a way to undo this effect when you need to change it yourself